# Lit-element checkbox not updated after reset

Tags: web-component, lit-element

I'm new with Lit-element and I'm trying to modify an exsiting library. This library creates a table of checkboxes based on three arrays. Arrays AAA and BBB are used as indexes, and array CCC is used to set the "checked" property.

These arrays can be realoaded via ajax, so the initial data is reset.

The problem is, if I manually  check/uncheck one checkbox an reset the data, the checkbox is not updated and the manual changes persist.

I've tried to add all three arrays to the "properties" section. Also I've created getters and setters. And finally I've tried to do a full requestUpdate", but nothing works.

Here is a piece of code (EDITED: replaced ?checked by .checked):

```
render(){
    return html`
    ...
        ${this.AAA.map(A => html`
             <tr>
                 ...
                 ${this.BBB.map(B => html`
                     <td>
                        ...
                        <input type="checkbox" .checked=${this.CCC[A].includes(B)} id="${A}:${B}"/>
                        ...
                    </td>
                `)}
            </tr>
        `)}
    ...
    `
}

static get properties() {
    return {
        //(added by me) Same for BBB and CCC
        AAA: { type: Array, hasChanged: (newVal, oldVal) => {
            return true;
        }},
        ...
    };
  }

//(added by me) Same for BBB and CCC
set AAA(newAAA){
    const oldAAA = this.AAA;
    this._AAA = newAAA;
    this.requestUpdate('AAA', oldAAA);
}

get AAA(){
    return this._AAA
}
```

Ajax Data might look like this:

```
{
  "AAA": [
    "xxx",
    "yyy",
    "zzz"
  ],
  "BBB": [
    "111",
    "222",
    "333"
  ]
  "CCC": {
    "xxx": [
      "111"
    ],
    "yyy": [
      "222",
      "333"
    ],
    "zzz": [
      "222"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here, a little example where you can try the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-fadxme

Some advise?
Thanks.

Comment: Try setting the [attribute instead of the property](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element/issues/601#issuecomment-469626034).

Comment: As @abraham suggested, I`ve replaced the property (?checked) with the attribute (.checked) but still not working. ("webcomponentsjs": "^2.2.10", "lit-element": "^2.1.0")

Comment: I've added a working example where you can see the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-fadxme

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do it modifying the shadowRoot/renderRoot in the "updated" method.

Input now is declared as:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-aaa="${A}" data-bbb="${B}" id="${A}:${B}"/>
```

instead of:

```
<input type="checkbox" .checked=${this.CCC[A].includes(B)} id="${A}:${B}"/>
```

And here the updated method:

```
updated(changedProperties) {
    var inputs = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
    inputs.forEach(elem => { 
      let A = elem.getAttribute('data-aaa');
      let B = elem.getAttribute('data-bbb');
      if(A && B){
        elem.checked = this.CCC[A] ? this.CCC[A].includes(B) : false;
      }
    })
    super.updated(changedProperties);
  }
```

Here the working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-fadxme

Anyway... what is preferible to use, shadowRoot or renderRoot?